# Start Activity inside onReceive BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, programming-languages, android-activity

I want to start an activity in my `onReceive()` method.

```
package com.splashscreenactivity;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String trigger_message = "";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // ---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";
        if (bundle != null) {
            // ---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                str += " :";
                trigger_message = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += trigger_message;
                str += "\n";
            }
            // ---display the new SMS message---
            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (trigger_message.equals("dx")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "I am triggered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                // /////////////////////////
                // i want to start here
                // ////////////////////////
                // MainScreenActivity.trigger="Now";
                // Intent i = new Intent(context,GPS.class);
                // i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                // context.startActivity(i);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "I am not triggered,  Bbyz!!!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is GPS.class

```
package com.splashscreenactivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GPS extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    TextView latitude, logitude;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gps);
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L, 500.0f,
                this);
        Toast.makeText(this, "i m started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        // latitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtLat);
        // logitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtLongi);
        // latitude.setText("Loading...");
        // logitude.setText("Loading...");
    }

    String LATTITUDE;
    String LOGITUDE;

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lag = location.getLongitude();
        LATTITUDE = Double.toString(lat);
        LOGITUDE = Double.toString(lag);
        // latitude.setText(LATTITUDE);
        // logitude.setText(LOGITUDE);
        // SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
        // // here is where the destination of the text should go
        // String number = "5556";
        // sm.sendTextMessage(number, null,
        // "latitude="+latitude.getText()+"\nlongitude="+logitude.getText(),
        // null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    }
    // /** Register for the updates when Activity is in foreground */
    // @Override
    // protected void onResume()
    // {
    // super.onResume();
    // lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L, 500.0f,
    // this);
    // }
    //
    // /** Stop the updates when Activity is paused */
    // @Override
    // protected void onPause() {
    // super.onPause();
    // lm.removeUpdates(this);
    // }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are getting?

Comment: You already have code that start activity. Just uncomment it.

Comment: Actually the startActivity method not working in the on receive method as this class not extends Activity

Comment: on uncommenting this code i m getting force quit on my emulator

Comment: post the stacktrace from the logcat to give us info about the error.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You have context passed as parameter to onRecieve() method, so just use:

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //start activity
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("com.test", "com.test.MainActivity");
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
```

It works, of course you have to change package and activity class name to your own.

Comment: sry i didn't get it can u pls elaborate!!

Comment: @piotrpo  if i m registering my broadcast reciever from manifest then can i start activity from broadcast reciever class using context.getApplicationContext.startActivity()  but my app crashed

Comment: I think that you should ask here for solution and paste your crash log.

Comment: my app is getting crashed when i used that..no activity found could you elaborate

Comment: not work on kitkat version . i check it , it work in all versions above 19 but not work on kitkat version

Comment: @piotrpo But if you register your broadcast receiver in the MyApplication class, it doesn't work

Comment: @Dr.jacky It's hard to say what `YourApplication.class` is doing.

Comment: @piotrpo Sorry, my bad. It works on `MyApplication.class` too.

Answer (score 30):

I am using this and its work on my site:

```
Intent intentone = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), DialogAct.class);
intentone.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intentone);
```

Comment: It's not working...new activity get launch with back stack of other Activity. Activity stack is not getting clear..any other suggestion!

Answer (score 6):

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent();
intent1.setClassName(context.getPackageName(), MainActivity.class.getName());
intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent1);
```

to prevent those package exceptions