# startActivity is not defined [android]

Tags: android

This is my code:

```
public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING || status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

        int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);

        intent = new Intent (context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Charging", isCharging);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I think it should work properly but I get an error at `startActivity()`. It looks like it was undefinded. Does anybody know what's wrong with this?

Comment: `context.startActivity(intent);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Start Activity inside onReceive BroadcastReceiver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468463/start-activity-inside-onreceive-broadcastreceiver)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BroadcastReceiver` does not extend `Context` and so it does not have the method `startActivity`. You should use the context that is passed to `onReceive` for that:

```
context.startActivity(intent);
```