# GPS is on, but the code is still not getting executed. Please see details

Tags: android, android-studio, gps, locationmanager, android-reactivelocation

I'm developing an app in which I want to execute a piece of code only if GPS is enabled.

I'm checking the GPS using this piece of code:

```
isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

And now, I'm using it like this:

```
if (isGPSEnabled) {
            gps_off.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ReactiveLocationProvider locationProvider = new ReactiveLocationProvider(getBaseContext());
            locationProvider.getLastKnownLocation()
                    .subscribe(new Action1<Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Location location) {
                            currentLatDoubleA = location.getLatitude();
                            currentLngDoubleA = location.getLongitude();
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "User's location retrieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
//        }
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    retrieveHRequest();
                }
            }, 2000);
        } else {
            gps_off.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(coordinatorLayout, "No location detected!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            ifLocationAvailable();
                        }
                    });
            snackbar.setDuration(Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
            snackbar.show();
        }
```

The problem is that even after turning the GPS on, the `Snackbar` is still popping up showing `No location detected!` message which means the code which is supposed to execute when GPS is off is getting executed even when GPS in on.

Another thing to note is that when I'm reopening the app after closing it, the code which should be executed when GPS is on is getting executed without any problem.

What's going wrong here?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In your application you want to implement broadcast receiver for observe changing the state of GPS. Then only the application understand about your changing status of GPS.

This code may helps you

```
 public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {

       @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            // gps enabled and do your action here        } else {
            // gps disabled and do you snack bar action
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how may I add/adjust this code according to the code given in the question?

Comment: <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
Add this to you manifest and follow the above code

Comment: thanks, but how can I use the above code in my main activity?

Comment: No, you can't use this code on your Activity class, you can invoke activity class function from BroadcastReceiver class

Comment: and how to do that? I mean how to invoke activity class function from BroadcastReceiver class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468463/start-activity-inside-onreceive-broadcastreceiver
this may helps you