# Is it possible to open the App from the Receiver in android 12?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Cant open the app from the android 12 from the receiver is there any solution to open the app from the receiver?

I tried to open the app from the broadcast receiver it is working fine below android version but not in the latest versions is there any solution.

Comment: If you have a BroadcastReceiver that is running, your app is already open technically. Do you mean you want to launch an Activity from a BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: Yes app is in background i wanted to open the app from the receiver.

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468463/start-activity-inside-onreceive-broadcastreceiver? If that doesn't work for you, edit your question to show what you tried. Also see: [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Android API level 29 places restrictions on what you can do here.  Read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts) for more information.

Comment: What actually im  trying is when we received the firebase push notification without clicking on the notification app needs to be launched is it possible?