# how to maximize the application on an event?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have minimized my app using this..

```
                Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(startMain);
```

The app is waiting for some event while it is in minimized state.How can i return to the app activity when some broadcast event occurs?

i can access the minimized activity from the the broadcast receiver class(using an object passed to it earlier) but it is running in the background of home screen.

and does android kill minimized apps eventually?

Comment: look into this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849868/startactivity-from-broadcastreceiver

Comment: i dont want to start a new activity...reopen the minimized one..

Comment: No, you did not `minimized` your application. There's not such thing in android.

Comment: add this android:launchMode="singleInstance" in your activity tag in manifest

Comment: @Webnet,well Eldhose's code worked for me..Thanks Sathya,Eldhose

Comment: I said there's not such thing like minimizing application on Android. All you did you launched something else, therefore your app's Activity was paused and went to background

Comment: sorry its my mistake..i should have used the term "gone to background" insted of "minimized"..i wanted to know if there was any way to bring it back to front.thanks man..

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(homeIntent);
```

this will start the HomeActivity, if the activity still in memory, it will just bring it to front.

Comment: doesn't it have the same effect without mentioned flag?

Comment: if there is instance of the activity in the history, it will not start a new instance of the activity

Comment: I see, I defined my activity as singleInstance, that's why I haven't seen any difference.

Comment: This is a perfect answer

Answer (score 1):

You can start the activity again using the Intent.

Example :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package.address","com.package.address.MainActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i wish i could.there is no option for me to choose it as right answer now(guess due to low reputation).
i will mark it as soon as i can.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maximize the application you need user interface in that case you can add your application in notification bar, once user click on notification bar you can open in your word can maximize the same. Adding your application in to notification bar you can get many tutorials :

[Notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)