# Send Array to Different Application

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-intent, broadcast

I would like to send an  array in different application.

So In the first application I have MainActivity. The Activity will start an intent. When I'm trying to make an intent, I found a problem. The problem is `ShowArrayActivity` "cannot be resolved to a type". Actually `ShowArrayActivity` class is in another apppication. I have tried to add project in build path, but I have an error message said that `a cycle was detected in the build path of project 'sendIntent'..`

```
package com.example.sendintent;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.example.sendintent.DisplayMessageActivity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String ARRAYS_COUNT = "com.example.sendintent.MainActivity.ARRAYS_COUNT"; 
    public static final String ARRAY_INDEX = "com.example.sendintent.MainActivity.ARRAY_INDEX";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) 
    {
        final String data[][] = new  String[][] 
                {{"Car","75","loaded"},
                 {"Motor","25","loaded"},
                 {"Truck","30","loaded"},
                 {"Bike","40","loaded"},
                 {"Boat","10","loaded"}};

         Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
         int count = data.length;

         bundle.putInt(ARRAYS_COUNT, count);

         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)

                 bundle.putStringArray(ARRAY_INDEX + i, data[i]);

         Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowArrayActivity.class); ---->ERROR

         intent.putExtras(bundle);
         startActivity(intent);


}
    }
```

In Manifest I have declare

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sendintent"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sendintent.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sendintent.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.sendintent.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.sendintent.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.example.sendintent.MainActivity" />
        <receiver android:name="com.example.receiver.MainActivityReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.example.sendintent.MainActivity.ARRAYS_COUNT"/>
          <action android:name="com.example.sendintent.MainActivity.ARRAYS_INDEX"/>
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

In another application, I have declare the receiver for the intent. It called MainActivityReceiver

```
package com.example.receiver;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.sendintent.MainActivity;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;


public class MainActivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        intent.setClass(context, MainActivity.class);
        context.startService(intent);             
    }

}
```

I have another class called ShowArrayAcivity:

```
package com.example.receiver;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class ShowArrayActivity extends Activity {
    public String[][] data;
    public static final String ARRAYS_COUNT = "com.example.sendintent.MainActivity.ARRAYS_COUNT"; 
    public static final String ARRAY_INDEX = "com.example.sendintent.MainActivity.ARRAY_INDEX";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();



            if (bundle != null) {

                    int count = bundle.getInt(ShowArrayActivity.ARRAYS_COUNT, 0);

                    ArrayList<String[]> arrays = new ArrayList<String[]>(count);

                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)

                            arrays.add(bundle.getStringArray(ShowArrayActivity.ARRAY_INDEX + i));

                    data = arrays.toArray(new String[][]{});
            }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

In Manifest for receiver application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.receiver"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.receiver.ShowArrayActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
             </activity>
  <service android:name="com.example.sendintent.MainActivity" />
  <receiver android:name="com.example.receiver.MainActivityReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.example.sendintent.MainActivity.ARRAYS_COUNT"/>
          <action android:name="com.example.sendintent.MainActivity.ARRAYS_INDEX"/>
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

In receiver application, It won't show the array from sendIntent application in Interface. I just want to know the way to use broadcast and intent. So if I run in debug mode,in `ShowArrayActivity`, the variable `data` will containt the result of the intent.
So my questions is,why I can't use another class when I try to send the intent? Did I forgot something to implement for madethe communication between 2 application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowArrayActivity.class);
```

this way you tell activity to find ShowArrayActivity within this Application and launch it. It fails as Application can't find it in it's manifest.

Create Intent with action.

```
Intent intent = new Intent (NAME_OF_THE_FILTER);
```

then replace string it second manifest

assuming

```
public static final String NAME_OF_THE_FILTER = "com.myapp.myfilter"


<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.myapp.myfilter"/>      
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: do I still need class receiver for receiver application?

Comment: You should follow sender activity > broadcast intent with action > system finds matching receiver > targeted app receiver (in manifest) > start activity() with intent matching target activity. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849868/startactivity-from-broadcastreceiver

Comment: The application is crashed when I implement with the way you said..Do you know how to check whether the intent is sending or not?

Comment: post the crash log. add Log.w() calls to sending methods and to receivers. then examine log.