# Open APP on GCM notification arrival

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want to open my android app as soon as notification is arrived without user interaction . But as my BroadcastReceiver cannot extend Activity so how I will I open another activity (as it requires Intent).

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getName());

    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
}
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849868/startactivity-from-broadcastreceiver)

Comment: Thanx a lot.! It worked.. @Raghavendra